# Babel transpiles exports external modules incorrectly

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am using

```
"babel-core": "^6.24.1",
"babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
"babili-webpack-plugin": "0.0.11",
"webpack": "^2.5.1"
```

In my `webpack.config.js` i have declared some external dependencies as:

```
externals: {
        "package-one": "package-one",
        "package-two": "package-two"
    },
```

The babel loader is configured as:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

And i initiate transpilation on a JS file that uses these packages using:

```
const p1 = require('package-one');
const p2 = require('package-two');
```

However, the transpiled output shows:

```
(function(module, exports) {
   module.exports = package-one;
}),
(function(module, exports) {
   module.exports = package-two;
})
```

As you can see, the exports are not surrounded by "" which causes errors in the final build. What may I be missing here?

Comment: try camel-case the values in externals

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html).

It explains how externals should be used

> ```
> externals: {
>     // require("jquery") is external and available
>     //  on the global var jQuery
>     "jquery": "jQuery"
> }
> ```

Therefore you need a valid name for your global variable for the external lib as such:

```
externals: {
    "package-one": "packageOne",
    "package-two": "packageTwo"
},
```

But of course packageOne and packageTwo must exist as global, this is what externals was meant to be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to set:

`libraryTarget: 'umd'`

in the `output` part of the `webpack.config.json`. This will allow you to use any sort of keys in the `externals`. Read more here:
http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-library-starter-using-webpack-es6